# How can I avoid the list error function in my code as I alter a list I am iterating?

Tags: python, count, append, primes

I am looking to use pop and remove functions to remove numbers from the list 2 to 100 in order to get a list of prime numbers. The main problem is that k always ends up causing an error. Also, when a put a print function after `k`, it shows up only even numbers, not sure why that is happening.

```
x=[] 
for i in range(2,100): 
    x.append(i)

primes=[]

count=0

while count < 99:
    k = x[count]
    print(k)
    primes.append(k)
    """for j in range(2,100):
        if k % j ==0:
            x.remove(j)"""
    x.pop(count)
    count = count + 1

print(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

Errors can happen because you are removing elements from a list while iterating over it.

Consider a list `[x, y, z]` and you're at position 0. If you decide to remove the element at position 0 then Python will move on to check position 1 in the next iteration of the loop. But position then refers to element `z` (because position 1 in the list `[y, z]` is `z`, not `y`).

Comment: What is the best way to handle this problem then of iterating and altering a list?

Comment: @user2983858: one should not iterate over a list while modifying it. So you figure out which elements you wish to remove and then after the loop you remove them.

Answer (score 2):

Your out of range:

x `len` is 98, and the `while` loop counts for 48 times....

You can fix it easily like that (Just fixed the While condition to `count < 48`):

```
    x=[]
    for i in range(2,100):
        x.append(i)

    primes=[]

    print len(x)

    count=0

    while count < 48:
        k = x[count]
        print(k)
        primes.append(k)
        """for j in range(2,100):
            if k % j ==0:
                x.remove(j)"""
        x.pop(count)
        count = count + 1

    print(x)
```

Comment: This will still throw an IndexError as one element of the list is removed by `pop` on each iteration...

Comment: @I4mpi You are right, don't know how it passed the first time i ran it, since we have `pop` each time, the limit is 48 times (0-47), i have edited the post, user2983858 still i think you should look Paulo solution since **i don't think you are in the right direction...**

Answer (score 0):

You aren't testing for prime numbers at all. You're getting only even numbers cause you're removing all odd ones. From the logic point there's no need to pre-polulate the list to further remove unwanted elements.

Here's what you're looking for:

```
def is_prime(n):
    if n < 2 or (n % 2) == 0:
        return n == 2

    f = 3

    while (f * f) <= n:
        if (n % f) == 0:
            return False

        f += 2

    return True

primes = [n for n in range(2, 100) if is_prime(n)]
print(primes)
```

Comment: while x is not empty: 
1. get the first element of x, call it k. 
2. pop it off of the list 
3. append it to primes 
4. remove all of the multiples of k from the list x